# Regex syntax highlighting question

Tags: c#, regex

Hey all, I' brand new to Regex and I've read several of the questions on here that are similar to what I'm looking for but I still cant wrap my head around it.

This is for syntax hightlighting, and I want to do it simlar to XAML where the attributes (the word preceeding the = as in "subject=" is red, the equals is still back, and then the data after the equals is a different color.

I know I can just use Find for the attributes, as those are known strings, but how can I match the string after the = (the data) to be able to color it?  Since it probably matters, the format I have to work with is "attribute=data ", so the data is over when a whitespace is detected

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I guess to clear this up a bit:

So here is part of a message, the a color inside paratheisis is not apart of the message, just what color I want it to be: "subject(red)=somedata(blue), message(red)={DATA(red)="somedata"(blue) HEADER(red)= " ect ect I guess looking at it, its not safe to say it always ends in a whitespace. I supose it should just end on a non-alpha character.

I tried using

```
string pattern = "\\s(\\S+)=(\\S+)\\s";
```

and that seemed to work a bit, but it colored the "=" the same as the value (I want the "=" to remain black) and for some reason it only grabbed a handful of them (but the ones it did grab it colored correctly, save the "=" thing)

Comment: Could you show demo "source code" of what you'd like parsed? Also, what have you tried already (was is partially successful?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression is

```
 \s(\S+)\s*="([^"]+)"
```

Have a look [here](http://www.rubular.com/r/ORjCofdPEv).

To use it in .NET:

```
string pattern = "\\s(\\S+)\\s*=\"([^\"]+)"\";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(inputString, pattern);
foreach(Match m in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value); // attrib name
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[2].Value); // attrib value
}
```

Comment: I'm kind of fond of `((?<tag>\S+)=(?<value>(?:\x22[^\x22]+\x22|[^>\s]+)))` personally.

Comment: Is there supposed to be an extra " at the end, before the ;? VS isnt liking that pattern statement, saying its an incomplete string. I dont wanna assume since it might mess up the RegEx

Comment: I meant that the format to be parsed does not have quotation marks in the value part.

Comment: They do not need it do they? If they need, all there is to move the brackets so they include the quotation: `\s(\S+)\s*=("[^"]+")`

Comment: Sorry I guess I need to clear it up a bit, this is confusing to think about haha. So here is part of a message, the a color inside paratheisis is not apart of the message, just what color I want it to be: subject(red)=somesubject(blue), message(red)={DATA(red)="somedata"(blue) HEADER(red)= ect ect

Comment: I guess looking at it, its not safe to say it always ends in a whitespace.  I supose it should just end on a non-alpha character.